# Looking for a binary counter/register IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu

A hobby of mine is to explore technologies and try to re-create simplified versions on my own, in order to better understand how they work. The current project I'm working on is to create a simple CPU using ICs (I don't want to do this from the transistor level, I'm not *that* into this...)

I can find lots of register chips for the general purpose registers, but the program counter (PC) would require a counter chip that is capable of being set arbitrarily (in order to achieve jump instructions).  Does anyone know of any ICs that are readily available that achieve this?  Alternately, if anyone has ever done this before, how do you make the PC?  Is it a single chip or do I need to create a separate PC circuit?

Comment: Instead of two paragraph question, have you tried 3 words google query?

Comment: specifically which words?  Also please note that the second part of this question asks for a bit more detail on the PC from more experienced users

Comment: Why the downvotes?  If this isn't a legitimate question, that's fine.  But please let me know what the problem is so that I can ask better questions in the future.  The comment that I should have googled this is fine as well, but I have and haven't really found anything I can work with.

Comment: Like "binary counter ic" query? And the second question is too broad (BTW, is the PC you are referring to is program counter? Or a personal computer?)

Comment: PC refers to program counter.  I'll edit the question.  From the question, though, I can find lots of binary counter ICs.  What I need is one that is also arbitrarily settable to enable the JMP instruction to work.  That's the hard part of my query.

Comment: JMP instruction is merely loading the register with a specific value. When claiming you could not find something you could work with, you should tell us what have you found and why it is not good enough for you.

Comment: You're asking a product to solve your issue. Asking for products is off topic. That's because lists of products do exist like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits  and you can also visit supplier sites like Mouser or Farnell which have many products all sorted by function or the IC manufacturer's sites like TI, NXP etc. Search there instead of asking here.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  So if all I have is a counter chip as my program counter, I'd need to count up or down until I get to the correct value.  Instead, what I'm looking for is a binary counter that allows me to  set the value without counting (like the other register chips I've found).  Hence the point of the question

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: thank you for the clarification.  I'll be sure to avoid these types of questions in the future

Comment: You need a counter which allows parallel loading.

Comment: I remember when all you needed was the T.I. bible.. Still a good place to start though. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls193.pdf

Comment: Try searching for "presettable binary counter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know of any ICs that are readily available that achieve
>   this?

Yes they are called FGPA's. You can make as many registers that you can fit into the FPGA and there is no wiring involved which saves you time. You can get dev boards for less than 30$USD. You could write your own instruction set and design your own processor architecture. You would have to learn an HDL (I reccomend VHDL) and how to simulate, but there are numerous tutorials on the internet to get you started. And you'd have a useful skill when you were done.

> Alternately, if anyone has ever done this before, how do you make the
>   PC? Is it a single chip or do I need to create a separate PC circuit?

You probably won't be able to put together a CPU, that is too detailed. It has been done, there was a guy that did a project [similar to this on a transistor level](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/23/brit_mega_processor/) took him a few years. Even with integrated logic and a simple CPU this would take a long time.

I built an [8088 computer by wirewrapping](https://www.google.com/search?q=8088%20wirewrap&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which included connecting the memory, ROM and I/O. This was for a university course, it takes about 6 weeks and takes about 40 hours a week. This sort of thing takes time, even without mistakes you will spend a few man-weeks implementing it.

The 'way' you do this is draw up your processor architecture with registers and wires, then find discreet logic IC's that will perform the function of each one.